# How to encode binary file inside JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use a HTML webpage that uses a .bin file with JavaScript.

I have found out that browsers don't support opening files from JS with anything BUT a protocol.
Console in Google Chrome throws the "`origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy`"

**HOWEVER**, could I paste the binary file's base64 value (e.g. data URI or JSON) inside the .HTML instead of asking it to open the file?

```
  ...
  var filename = "recipes_0_" + cut_cost + "_" + stack_cost + (singleLayerIsRaw?"r":"") + ".bin";
  load_binary_resource( filename );
}

function onPageLoad() {
  document.getElementById("code").disabled = true;
  //load_binary_resource("[base64 value]");
```

instead of

```
  document.getElementById("code").disabled = true;
  //load_binary_resource("myfile.bin");
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You have a binary file and don't know how to encode it as base64?

Comment: And it's perfectly possible to fetch binary files if they are accessible via http. So as long as you have a server, you don't need to encode it into the html

Comment: [MDN data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs)